# the system spontaneously reboots once every day

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I have a brand new system that was just built a few days ago, it has 4 NVidia Titan X GPUs, 8x16Gb Gskill DDR4-2400 memory, on an Asus X99-E WS motherboard, running Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm looking for ways to figure out what caused these random reboots, the system wasn't even doing anything, it just sits idle...and it happened several times already! There shouldn't be any overheating as the CPU is water-cooled, and I have lm-sensor that shows the GPUs having around 35C temp on idle, and whenever the system reboots itself (while I'm away), it's always doing nothing so overheating shouldn't be the issue here.

I did `last reboot` and found several more self-reboots that I wasn't aware of, and so I went to my `/var/log/kern.log` in hope to see something informative. I found that at around every minute, it has this error message logged:

```
AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=0018
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0018(Receiver ID)
device [8086:6f08] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
[6] Bad TLP
```

and then right before the spontaneous reboot, the following is logged:

```
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

followed by the rebooting log:

```
[0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
...
```

What does it tell me? Or am I looking at the wrong log file?

Comment: Is your powersupply strong enough to power all this hardware?

Comment: should be ok, the power supply is a EVGA 1600w. The issue is that it spontaneously restarts even at idle, so I'm wondering if I can find any error messages from any of the log files that can give me clues of whether it is motherboard, memory, driver, GPU, CPU, etc that's causing this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out to be a bad bios by Asus!

I looked around online and it seems that people who have Asus's Rampage series (X99) motherboard and high-end Nvidia cards are also having this spontaneous rebooting issue, and the issue seems to be surrounding a bad bios.

Those folks claim that newer Bios of version 3xxx is causing this random restarts, but if they fall back to the Bios version of 2xxx then it is stable as a rock.

Even though my motherboard is an Asus (X99-E WS) but not a Rampage, but my Bios is 3101 so I tried to see if I can find a bios version 2xxx for my motherboard. While I couldn't find one to fall back to, Asus just happened to have released a new Bios (v3302) for my motherboard THREE DAYS AGO, I tried that and it has been running fine with no random restarts for 2 days. Hopefully this fixed the issues...!

Comment: Can you please give a link to where you found useful info? I am having the *exact* same symptoms, but with an MSI motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a kernel bug. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109691#c2 suggests to turn off AER by adding `pci=noaer` to the kernel command line in grub.
You could for example add it to `/etc/default/grub` around line 12:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pci=noaer"
```

Does this solve these issues?

Comment: will try it, but I found that in my `/var/log/auth.log` file, I get this message right before the self-reboot
`dbus[986]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.40" (uid=0 pid=2206 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=1084 comm="NetworkManager ")`

does that mean something?

Comment: This dbus message has nothing to do with your problem. It's a known buglet in Ubuntu. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

You're having a problem with a PCI device ID 8086:6f08. In terminal, type `lspci` and locate the line containing 8086:6f08, and I suspect that it'll point to one of your Nvidia GPU's. If there are four separate cards, pull all but one and see if you continue to show errors. Keep adding back GPU's until it shows errors. You may have a bad card, or a GPU BIOS/firmware/software that needs updating. Check the Nvidia site for that.

edit: or `lsusb` and identify a USB device or controller.

Let me know how you do. Cheers, Al